# How can I add logs to the runtime for debugging since `--execution native` has been removed?

Tags: log, debug

The node always uses on-chain wasm for execution. How can I add new logs to debug the production chain?

Comment: Nice question. I have struggled with this several times. The solution that I used recently is using `--override-runtime` feature to replace the runtime with the tweaked runtime. Obviously, this is not friendly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also use [Chopsticks](https://github.com/AcalaNetwork/chopsticks/tree/master) to replay blocks and see the logs. Again, you need to have `--wasm-override` to use a wasm with logging enabled and `--runtime-log-level=5` to enable verbose logs.

Depends on what you want to do, you may set the block number to the one before the block you want to replay, and send the tx and see the output, or use the `run-block` subcommand / `dev_runBlock` RPC to run the block.

Answer (score 1):

You can run your node with `--wasm-runtime-overrides PATH_TO_FOLDER`. Where `PATH_TO_FOLDER` contains one or more wasm files that will be used to override the on chain wasm. Overriding is done based on the `spec_version`. You also want to ensure that the override is producing the same state changes as the on chain wasm to continue syncing.