# How to debug an extrinsic (the runtime code) after migration to wasm-only execution in Polkadot?

Tags: runtime, wasm, debugging

Polkadot is moving away from native execution mode and in the first step they [removed the native execution mode](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/pull/14387). This means that the `--execution Native` does not work anymore which is the solution in similar questions.

With the wasm-only runtime in action, how may I debug an extrinsic in a debugger **without using logs** . I tried setting a breakpoint on the corresponding line of code and also function name in both rust-lldb and rust-gdb but the breakpoints are not hit.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I add logs to the runtime for debugging since \`--execution native\` has been removed?](https://substrate.stackexchange.com/questions/10540/how-can-i-add-logs-to-the-runtime-for-debugging-since-execution-native-has-b)

Comment: No, it's about using logs. I know about the logs already and specifically made it bold to emphasis that.

Answer (score 1):

I've not tried either, but looks like there're at least two options

- [LLDB with Wasmtime](https://docs.wasmtime.dev/examples-debugging.html) or
- a WASM specific debugger like [wasminspect](https://github.com/kateinoigakukun/wasminspect)

Source: https://shopify.engineering/debugging-server-side-webassembly